# Python argparse helper section

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

Just started using argparse for parsing commands.

I have a command arg that is -l. This argument takes 2 args from user.

```
-l ONE_ARG TWO_ARG
```

In the help file using argparse, I get the following:

```
-l L L      Some message for this argument
```

How can I replace the 'L' to give a small temple of what the user needs to put into those arguments like so.

```
-l "First_Name" "Last_Name"        Some message for this argument
```

Basically something more descriptive than 'L L' which means nothing to the user really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best options is to use metavars, https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#metavar which gives

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', nargs=2, 
       help = "Some message for this argument", 
                    metavar=('"First Name"', '"Second Name"'))
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

A more flexible but less elegant answer may be to manually specify the exact help you want:

```
import argparse

def print_names():
    outstr = "usage: scriptname -l 'First Name' 'Second Name' "
    outstr += "Some message for this argument "
    print(outstr)

 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.add_argument('-l', help=print_names(), nargs=2)
 args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```